# jTextField no se actualiza con evento de teclado

Tags: java

Buenas, intento hacer un campo donde no pueda escribir números, solo caracteres alfabeticos [a-zA-Z] en un jTextField. Lo que quiero es que al digitar letras que cumplan esto se coloquen en el textField y si son numero u otra cosa no se coloquen, o por lo menos se actualice para borrarla, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    char keyCode = e.getKeyChar();  //obtenemos el codigo de la tecla 
    String keyText = String.valueOf(keyCode);  //luego el caracter 
    System.out.println(cadena);
    System.out.println("Tecla digitada: " + keyText);
    try {
        escribir(keyText);
    } catch (MyException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private void escribir(String a) throws MyException {  
//Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*");  
    Pattern pat2 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");  
    Matcher mat = pat2.matcher(a);  
    if (mat.matches()) {  
        cadena = cadena + a;  
        System.out.println(cadena);  
    } else {  
        throw new MyException("Caracteres no permitidos, solo [A-Z], [a-z]");  
    }  
    jTextField1.setText(cadena);  
}
```

Pero sin embargo el textfield sigue escribiendo cualquier caracter, como ven intento setear el texto cada vez que se ejecuta el evento keyPressed pero esto no sucede, coloca las letras pero la cadena esta correcta, no acepta nada que no sea alfabetico.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los mensajes son del catch cuando atrapa la excepción que cree.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es donde has colocado las escritura de la cadena (el `jTextField1.setText(cadena);`). Donde está actualmente, siempre escribirá el texto, tanto si ingresan letras como otro carácter. Esta cadena debería ser escrita siempre y cuando se cumpla la condición que estas usando, te quedaría así:

```
if (mat.matches()) { 
    cadena = cadena + a;
    System.out.println(cadena);
    jTextField1.setText(cadena);
}else{
    //...
```